# How do I extract missing digits from an integer?

Tags: c++, syntax, while-loop, extract, digits

I'm trying to get the following output:

```
Enter integer: 87240

Missing digits: 1 3 5 6 9
```

Here is my code so far:

```
// Extract numbers inside integer n

while (numOfDigits > 0)
{    
    int digit = n % 10;

    int missing = 0;

    while ((digit != missing) && (missing < 10))
    {
        cout << missing << " ";
        missing++;
    }

    numOfDigits--;
    n /= 10;
}
```

which prints out

```
Enter integer: 87240

Missing digits: 0 1 2 3 0 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Is there any way to go about doing this without using an array?

Comment: Personally I would just take the number in as a string and then check if each digit exists using `find()`.

Comment: What do you mean "without using an array"? Where does your code use an array?

Comment: I think he means to do that without using array (as he tries to do), which is normally needed (e.g. to filter out the used numbers). Still, the required size of the array (10 items) is not terribly big, so I'd probably do it with arrays to allow O(n) runtime instead of O(n^2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Arrays in this one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int NumHasDigit(int num, int digit)
{
    while (num)
    {
        if (num%10 == digit) 
        {
            return 1;
        }
        num /= 10;
    }   
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int x;

    printf("Enter int: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &x);

    printf("Missing Digits:\n");
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        if (!NumHasDigit(x,i)) printf("%d ", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Input:**
`34567`

**Sample Output:**
`Missing Digits`
`0 1 2 8 9`

Comment: My understanding is that `digits` is an array and OP says without using an array.

Comment: Any particular reason why this returns `int` instead of a `bool`?

Comment: Because I'm an old-school C programmer... from before `bool` existed.  You wanna change it? That's your work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation that uses a single integer (`acc`) to remember which digits had been seen:

```
#include <iostream>

using uuint = unsigned long long int;

uuint p(uuint n) { ++n; return n * n - n + 41; }

void print_missing(uuint n)
{
    std::cout << "Number " << n << " is missing the following digits:";
    uuint acc = 1;
    while (n)
    {
        uuint q = p(n % 10);
        if (acc % q != 0) acc *= q;
        n /= 10;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
    {
        if (acc % p(i) != 0) std::cout << " " << i;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    for (uuint n; std::cin >> n; )
        print_missing(n);
}
```

Comment: Yes, "cheating" by using array of bits (a number) instead of regular array of 10 items. Btw. it should be enough to have just 10 bits to store the information (when using bit shifts and bit operations), so `unsigned short` (at least 2B) should be enough to accumulate the result ;)

Comment: @axalis: I guess that makes even talking about the problem cheating! :-)

Comment: I'd like to comment that I'm upvoting this not because it's a good solution, but because it meets the requirements of a bad question.

Comment: @JonathanMee: Your position has been recorded. Nobody will take your upvote as endorsement of my code :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you interested in using a `string` instead of an array, perchance? Those *are* more or less the same idea, but given the input `string n` we could find any unused digits like this:

```
const auto digits = "0123456789"s;

sort(begin(n), end(n));
set_difference(cbegin(n), cend(n), cbegin(digits), cend(digits), ostream_iterator<char>(cout, " "));
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/gu0W8j)

Comment: I did not know `set_difference` and wrote it myself more than once. Thank you!

Comment: @YSC Like you I learned most of my standard algorithms by seeing people on here utilize them. But if you're planning on being more than a casual C++ programmer it might not hurt to read through this list: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

Comment: I love `<algorithm>`  and functional programming in general; but they're considered too complicated by too many people. And since readability is preferred over my personal enjoyment, I use an imperative style. Life is so sad...

Comment: @YSC Wow... this is gonna sound sarcastic cause everything's sarcastic online, but seriously, that is like the saddest thing I've heard all week :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop, no need for an array:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  std::string integer;
  std::cout << "Enter integer: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, integer);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    const char c = '0' + i;
    if (integer.find(c) == std::string::npos)
    {
      cout << i << " ";
    }
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The above version keeps the number in text form, easier to search for digits.
You could use a nested loop to check every digit of the number.

Comment: However fair to notice that `std::string` is indeed an array, so it doesn't fit the "without using array" requirement. And also will be probably slower than the "regular array" version, as this will require to traverse the string (and compare numbers) 10 times instead of once.

Answer (score 1):

Here the version using a single integer to accumulate the results (still, technically array of bits):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void check(int n)
{
    unsigned short bits = 0;
    while (n) {
        bits |= 1 << std::abs(n % 10);
        n /= 10;
    }
    std::cout << "Missing digits:";
    for (unsigned i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
        if (((bits >> i) & 1) == 0)
            std::cout << " " << i;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    check(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to comment that I'm upvoting this not because it's a good solution, but because it meets the requirements of a bad question.